# Ionic Audio Recording with Capacitor

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, chat, capacitor

I just finished my chat app but i want the voice msg be like messenger not file.wav
any idea please

[image]

any idea please
ionic 6 , plugin:capacitor-voice-recorder

Comment: Is this the plugin you are using? https://github.com/tchvu3/capacitor-voice-recorder

Answer (score -3):

1. Looking for a plugin? You already have the name.
2. Looking for example? That plugin provides an example.

Comment: the display of my msg is file.wav but I want a display of a voice message like messenger

Comment: You need to create UI for it and use the audio plugin to play the file. There is no drag an drop component for what you are asking.